# Nginx server for static content

Tags: macos, nginx

What is the minimum needed to start an Nginx server to serve static content (js etc)?

I've got:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /Users/matt/Dev;
        }
    }
}

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

But I get:

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I've run `sudo nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 0):

By default when we run Nginx as `root`, e.g. `sudo nginx ...`, Nginx will start a master process by `root` and listens on one or more http ports given but for security reason it will start several worker processes by user `nobody`. Those worker processes will handle incoming requests. We can check this by run

**UPDATE** : change `ps -ef` to `ps aux` because when on macosx/freebsd `ps -ef` does not show user

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
```

In your case because user `nobody` has no permission to access /Users/matt/Dev so we'll  get no-permission-error when accessing the related location.

To fix it we can try either of

1. define user in nginx.conf, e.g.  `user matt;` OR
2. set access permission of /Users/matt/Dev. Please note that we need also make sure user nobody has search permission (viz. x-permission) to access all directories in the path prefix of pathname, e.g. /Users, /Users/matt, /Users/matt/Dev, and has read permission of /Users/matt/Dev and its child files.

Comment: It isn't enough. It will need `autoindex` as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @uzsolt I don't think enable `autoindex` is a good choice unless we just setup a download site because it is often unsafe and maybe causes some private sources or db configurations to leak out. BTW If there is no index.html file in `/Users/matt/Dev`, use directive `index` to define the default index files , e.g. `index my-index-file.html;` more details can be found http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index

Comment: Yes, another option is to create an index file. But only the permissions (as suggested in your answer) aren't enough.

Answer (score 0):

With your config you can access individual files. So you can get `example.com/example.js` (try it and you can see it works).

With `example.com` you want to show the content of root directory (`/Users/matt/Dev`) which is disabled. To enable use `autoindex`:

```
location / {
    root /Users/matt/Dev;
    autoindex on;
}
```

See more information [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html):

> The ngx_http_autoindex_module module processes requests ending with
>   the slash character (‘/’) and produces a directory listing.

Comment: I think apache is using that address but don't know how to check

Comment: Do you run apache too?